# How to display text in textarea word by word or letter by letter using animations - Angular

Tags: angular, anime.js

I want to show display multiline text in a textarea with some animation.line by line , word by word  or similar

I am trying to get this stackblitx working for textarea
https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-animation-demo-with-animejs-nhpi9n?file=src/app/app.component.ts

It works for h3, but when I apply same css class for textarea it is not working

would be great, if I can get help on the fix. Nice if I get a cursor like pen too

[image]

Comment: For textarea this is not posible. You can go with other options.

Comment: Please can you tell the available options. I have multiline text, hence used textarea. Now I want some animation

Comment: I have updated the stackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-animation-demo-with-animejs-nhpi9n?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Now, how can I show required data in multiple lines. i.e. display  ml:string="1600 \n Amphitheatre \n Pkwy"; in multiple lines. My data comes in one long line with newline character.  Please suggest

Comment: Updated code  - textWrapper.innerHTML = this.ml.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

Comment: Solved my issue - using pre instead of div !

Comment: Can you show that What is your use-case for this ?

Comment: @GRD please check the stackblitz. use case is to display data line by line than dump. This will enable user to follow the steps line by line

Comment: I have a follow up question - I want to hide and show the control, but anime is not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-animation-demo-with-animejs-qdhmpk?file=src/app/app.component.html . Steps to recreate: (1) Change showIt:boolean = true; to false (2) uncomment the line // this.showIt = ! this.showIt; . Any help appreciated. Question 2 - My use case UI is a stepper , and anime is working only in the first step (guess its because of selector...but how to fix?)

Comment: @GRD works perfectly. can you help me understand the change. the lamdba kind of function => . .. Question 2 is also key for me. I have stepper control and this box is just below the stepper. So not inside mat-horizontal-stepper. The code const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.an-1'); seems to work only once . i.e. in the first step. when I click next the control is not displayed. The control is <pre  #detailedSteps class="viewSteps" name="explanation{{rowIdx}}" ></pre>

Comment: I can't get what you are saying . Can you explain further? Control is not displaying ? Means ?

Comment: @GRD added image to question, see if that helps. I want to show that control in every step. I thought it is worth mentioning that the anime control is outside </mat-horizontal-stepper>

Comment: Check showIt property value when you change from one step to next step

Comment: I used a textarea before and that works i.e. the value changes for each step -> <textarea matInput class="lineheight" [(ngModel)]="exm.ans[rowIdx].formattedAnswer" name="explanation" readonly="readonly"></textarea>. But pre is not displaying for stepper step 2.  I m trying to create a stackblitz with stepper and anime , but unable to fork now. I do not know why , but will update if that gets created

Comment: Note: I see a few errors around ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name:<<the name of my pre>> . This is happening even for my first step

Comment: Please send more details to my email ID : `grdtechlab@gmail.com` . It would be more easy to communicate over it.

Comment: pls check email